# Get data drom array saved in database

Tags: php

I need to read arrays saved in database to get specific variables.

```
Array
(
[0] => PHPMailer Object (
                  [From] => email@mail.com
                  [FromName] => John Doe
      )
)
```

I tried

```
echo "From".$row[0]["From"];
```

But it returns

```
From : P
```

Comment: `echo "From".$row[0]->From;` try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PHPMailer` has a `From` property. You should be able to access it like this:

`echo("From: " . $row[0]->From);`

Comment: We all seemed to jump in on this 

Comment: I don't know why but i got empty result

Comment: I'm sorry accidentally I used `+` instead of `.`. Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

`From` and `FromName` are object so you can get it using `->`. try:

```
echo "From".$row[0]->From;
```